# @Post Jersey Only one unannotated parameter is allowed in a method with javax.ws.rs.POST annotation

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey with the propose to do an webservice.

I'm trying to do is a @Post method that recibes 3 params by form and 1 by url.

```
@POST
@Path("/{contestType}/pay")
public Response pay(@PathParam("contestType") String contestType,
        @FormParam("contestId") Long contestId, @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("amount") Long amount)
{
    User user = dao.getByKey(User.class, username);
    if (user == null)
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode(), "username not valid").build();

    Contest contest = dao.getByKey(Contest.class, contestId);
    if (contest == null)
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode(), "contest not valid").build();

    try
    {
        if (contestType.equals("raffles"))
            user.pay(contest, amount);
        else
            user.pay(contest);
    }
    catch (ContestException | PaymentException e)
    {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.WARNING, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

But when i do that i get a warning from eclipse : Only one unannotated parameter is allowed in a method with javax.ws.rs.POST annotation.
And also when is executed I get the next error:

message java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
causa raíz
```

I need to recibe an Json from the client, so i can't use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, also don't want to create infinite POJO objects for each @Post i have, what is the correct way to beat this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@FormParam` is supposed to be used for requests where the payload is a form (and the method is annotated with `@Consumes` with a value such as `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`).

Consider the following code:

```
@POST
@Path("/{contestType}/pay")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response pay(@PathParam("contestType") String contestType,
                    @FormParam("contestId") Long contestId, 
                    @FormParam("username") String username,
                    @FormParam("amount") Long amount) {
    ...
}
```

It expects the input in the following format:

```
POST /api/foo/pay HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

contestId=1&username=johndoe&amount=1000
```

---

If your payload is a JSON document, then `@FormParam` is not suitable for you. *The JAX-RS runtime won't extract values from the JSON document in the payload and bind them to method parameters.* In this situation, define a class to bind the JSON document to:

```
public class PaymentDetails {

    private Long contestId;
    private String username;
    private Long amount;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```
@POST
@Path("/{contestType}/pay")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response pay(@PathParam("contestType") String contestType,
                    PaymentDetails paymentDetails) {
    ...
}
```